# taskmgr.exe - Wrong Volume

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, task-manager

The other day my girlfriend used my computer to use one of those additional resource CD's that come with text books. This particular CD worked by acting like what seemed like a web server that hosted a site that the student is supposed to use (cgi-bin, python scripts...the whole deal).

Today, I opened task manager to shut down some rogue IE's and got the following in an error popup with the title **taskmgr.exe - Wrong Volume** and Cancel/Try Again/Continue buttons:

> The wrong volume is in the drive. Please insert volume DosageCalc into drive D:

(FYI: DosageCalc = nursing student)

Clicking Cancel or Continue lets me continue to task manager. The CD hasn't been in the drive for days and I've used it since then with no problems. Where could task manager be holding onto this reference? My guess would be the registry somewhere...but I don't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/12/10089878.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebooted your PC since the software was used?  It is possible that the installer is still running in the background looking for the install CD.  Rebooting should resolve the problem if the problem was just withe application not closing properly.